# OpenAI GPT-3 API error: "You didn't provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in an Authorization header using Bearer auth"

Tags: php, openai-api, gpt-3

I am getting an error for the following PHP code:

```
$curl = curl_init("https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/davinci/completions");

$data = array(
  'prompt' => 'how many sundays in 2023',
  'max_tokens' => 256,
  'temperature' => 0.7,
  'model' => 'text-davinci-003'
);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Authorization: Bearer sk-MY-API-KEY']);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$result = json_decode($result);
print $result->choices[0]->text;
```

I correctly provided the API Key, but getting this error:

> Error message: You didn't provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in an Authorization header using Bearer auth (i.e. Authorization: Bearer YOUR_KEY)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem

All [Engines API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/deprecations/2022-06-03-legacy-endpoints) endpoints are deprecated.

[image: Deprecated]

#### Solution

Use the [Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/completions-api) endpoint.

Change the URL from this...

```
https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/davinci/completions
```

...to this.

```
https://api.openai.com/v1/completions
```

#### Working example

If you run `test.php` the OpenAI API will return the following completion:

> string(23) "
>
> This is indeed a test"

**test.php**

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();

    $url = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/completions';

    $api_key = 'sk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

    $post_fields = '{
        "model": "text-davinci-003",
        "prompt": "Say this is a test",
        "max_tokens": 7,
        "temperature": 0
    }';

    $header  = [
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $api_key
    ];

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    $response = json_decode($result);
    var_dump($response->choices[0]->text);
?>
```

Comment: Changed the URL as you suggested, but still getting this error: "message": "You didn't provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in an Authorization header using Bearer auth (i.e. Authorization: Bearer YOUR_KEY),  "type": "invalid_request_error",

Comment: *Start experimenting with $18 in free credit that can be used during your first 3 months.*

Comment: I have enough credits and my API key is correct and active. But still it doesn't work.

Comment: What if you revoke the current and issue a new API key?

Comment: Also, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75050771/php-curl-open-ai-remove-the-quotes-from-post-data.